# Why does node semver use 'latest' in dist-tags as max version for satisfied versions?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, semantic-versioning

I was trying to figure out how npm install select versions for dependencies, here is my finding:

`rollup-plugin-uglify@3.0.0` has dependencies as follow:

```
dependencies: {
    uglify-es: "^3.3.7"
}
```

After I install, this is the result from `npm ls`:

```
└─┬ rollup-plugin-uglify@3.0.0
  └─┬ uglify-es@3.3.9
    ├── commander@2.13.0
    └── source-map@0.6.1
```

The installed version for `uglify-es` is 3.3.9 while the newest version is 3.3.10 [ref link](https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-es).
Then I checked this official online [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/),and find this logic in the website source code:

```
$scope.checkVersions = function() {
          var maxVersion = latest
           if (!semver.satisfies(maxVersion, $scope.range)) maxVersion = null;
          for (var i=0, len=versions.length; i<len; i++) {
            $scope.versions[i].satisfies = distTags[$scope.range] === $scope.versions[i].version ||
              (semver.satisfies($scope.versions[i].version, $scope.range) &&
               (!maxVersion || semver.lte($scope.versions[i].version, maxVersion)));
          }
        }
```

It seems if the 'latest' version in dist-tag satisfies the given range, then it will be the max version of satisfied version. In this case, the 'latest' in dist-tag for `uglify-es` is 3.3.9, that's why the 3.3.10 is not chosen.

I just want to ask for the reason for such design, and since I am also working on npm dependency tree calculation, is there any documentation for detailed dependency parsing rules for small tricks like this?

Comment: The [latest](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm-versions#the-latest-release-of-npm) release of a package is typically the most recent stable version. It's quite uncommon, (as is the case with `uglify-es`), to have a release that is greater than the `latest` version available in the npm registry too (...which is not a pre-prelease version `alpha`, `beta` etc of course!). So yes it does seem unconventional that `uglify-es` has `3.3.9` tagged as `latest`, yet `3.3.10` (a non pre-release) has been published too.

Comment: btw. you mentioned _"I am also working on npm dependency tree calculation"_ - for that use the [semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) package, which is what is utilized by the [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) online tool and `npm`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have used the satisfies api in node-semver in my parser, but that tool is purely for version's calculation, for cases like this 'uglify-es' can not be resolved correctly. I need to build an offline scan for js dependencies, so I have to implement the dependency tree calculation algorithm again, but it is difficult to find very detailed documents on this... thanks again for your kind reply.

Comment: You're welcome - `uglify-es` seems to be a case of semantic versioning starting to be done unconventionally, and is likely to create issues for users in the future. By convention, the `3.3.10` release should have probably been released as a [prerelease](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag.html#purpose), i.e. something like `4.0.0-[alpha|beta].0` or as a release candidate; `4.0.0-rc.0` depending on it's current stage of development. A project such as `eslint` take the correct idealistic approach to semver, e.g. run `npm show eslint dist-tags && npm show eslint versions` and check the results.

Comment: Yes, I also think the 'latest' tag should be only used as the real latest stable version. I will add the same logic as given above to handle such cases for now. thank you!

Comment: Because the latest tag has nothing to do with SemVer and is just a movable tag in the NPM repository system, you should always treat that tag with whatever logic NPM applies to it.  It has nothing to do with SemVer.  I believe it can be arbitrarily assigned to any version.  The [carrot range notation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) is also an NPM idiom that has nothing to do with SemVer and works with all version strings that have the dotted decimal field format (ie,^0.3.1.2 is a valid NPM range).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the logic that NPM applies to latest, has changed in the past and is subject to change in the future.

Comment: I believe the latest tag logic, and the NPM version range notations, predates NPM's adoption of SemVer.  NPM supports other version string types where semantic meaning differs, if defined at all, from that of SemVer.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's npm's adoption of SemVer, and the npm's official tool on semver `node-semver` is the one which npm really use when parsing semantic versions. However, the latest tag logic is not implemented as part of `node-semver`, it seems only exist in `npm-install`. Thanks for your kind explanation!

Comment: Right, it's a feature of their online feed service.